# Error message shown as [object Object] when use require, how to get actual error message string in Remix IDE Console?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, remix, error, require

I have used require function as:

```
require(owner == msg.sender, "Sender must be owner");
```

But in the remix console I got,

```
transact to Contract.setAdmin errored: [object Object]
```

What should I do to get proper error message? Also the same contract, using metamask is successfully deployed on Rinkeby. Is it the matter of traffic on that testnet?

Comment: This error doesn't look like it has anything to do with the `require` statement in your code.

Comment: So why I am getting [object Object] ?

Comment: Because you are doing something wrong of course.

Comment: @RudrikaFichadiya Which ethereum node are you using to deploy your contracts? ie geth, parity, ganache, etc. Remix gets the message from the node, it is not standarized how to get the error message so it may not work for every client.

Comment: @Ismael, I am using Injected Web3 & Metamask to deploy my contract on testnet.

Comment: @RudrikaFichadiya I don't know what is going on, it seems somewhere between the testnet, metamask and remix the error isn't passed properly.

Comment: @Ismael, when I try to deploy the same contract on Rinkeby it totally works fine. On the other hand simple transfer of ether between my accounts are not getting confirmation from blockchain in ropsten test network.

Comment: @RudrikaFichadiya If you have other issues it is better to create a new question, otherwise you can edit a question to add more details.

Comment: @Ismael Yes I have added more details in the same question.